# iOS .plist naming conventions

Tags: ios, naming-conventions, plist

What are the naming conventions when dealing with `.plist` files in iOS applications.

Specifically:

- Naming conventions for the file names
- Naming conventions for the keys used

Thanks.

Comment: More context would be nice. What files? Where are the keys used?

Comment: I am just asking in general. Files = `.plist` files stored locally in the app. Keys will be used from within the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no naming convention for files per-se. However I observed that key constants are usually being defined like this:

In SomeClass.h file

```
extern NSString * const MyValueKey;
```

In SomeClass.m file

```
NSString * const MyValueKey = @"MyValue";
```

ie. the key constant has suffix "Key", while the value for that constant is without it.

Then let's say you have dictionary in plist (here - in json format):

```
{
    "MyValue": "Some string"
}
```

After reading plist with that dictionary inside it you can do:

```
NSString * someString = dictFromPlist[MyValueKey];
```

Comment: So the keys should follow the "UpperCammelCase" convetion ?

Comment: Almost everything in ObjectiveC follows CammelCase convention. Event the language title itself ,)

Comment: The actual language name is "Objective-C" ;)